# Angular Textinput Components doesn't work with array

Tags: angular, typescript

i want a collection of textinput components with values stored in an array. But when i use the code below, the values take the wrong places in the array and i can't find the bug.

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let option of this.options;let i = index">
    <td style="width:100%">
      <textinput2 (textchange)="this.options[i] = $event;" class="lessmargin" type="text" [value]="this.options[i]">
      </textinput2>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
      <button [attr.disabled]="this.options.length >= 3 ? null:''" (click)="this.options.splice(i, 1)" style="top:0;" class="btn btn-outline-danger">-</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<a (click)="this.options.push('')" class="showmore">+ weitere Option hinzufügen</a>
```

Textinput2 Component:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label *ngIf="this.placeholder && this.labelsize == 'big'" for={{randomid}}><h5>{{this.placeholder}}</h5></label>
  <label *ngIf="this.placeholder && this.labelsize == 'small'" for={{randomid}}>{{this.placeholder}}</label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="this.value" (change)="this.textchange.emit(this.value)" type={{type}} id={{randomid}} class="form-control" placeholder={{this.placeholder}}>
</div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get what is going on but you maybe need to use `trackBy` in your *ngFor

According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) :

> A function that defines how to track changes for items in the iterable.
>
> When items are added, moved, or removed in the iterable, the directive must re-render the appropriate DOM nodes. To minimize churn in the DOM, only nodes that have changed are re-rendered.
>
> By default, the change detector assumes that the object instance identifies the node in the iterable. When this function is supplied, the directive uses the result of calling this function to identify the item node, rather than the identity of the object itself.
>
> The function receives two inputs, the iteration index and the node object ID.

You can learn more how to use it [there](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5)